# How to use "Includes" functionality in SQL?

Tags: sql

I require following functionality, How can I frame it in a query?

```
Select * 
from table 
where column 4 includes column3
```

Example:
Please find attachment for table screenshot.

[image: Table structure].

I want to extract all the rows where column 4 includes column 3.

Comment: Removed conflicting rdbms product tags. Add back the one you use. Pls wlso specify what you mean by include because that is not clear.

Comment: Maybe the [LOCATE function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php) might help you, if the tag of "Mysql" was correct (I see it has vanished now). However, this means you could do a `WHERE LOCATE(column3, column4) > 0`

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table where column4=column3
```

Comment: This will not give a hit on row 3, which I suspect he wants a hit on, since column 3 is "included" within the content of column 4.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LIKE statement with the "value" from column3

```
select *
from the_table
where column4 like '%'||column3||'%'
```

`||` is the ANSI SQL operator for string concatenation, but not all DBMS respect that.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a string find function or something along those lines, and as I saw this being tagged with Mysql, you should be able to use [LOCATE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    LOCATE(column3, column4) > 0
```